# Suggested edits to deleted posts remaining in /review with Approve/Reject buttons

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

In some cases, questions and answers that have been deleted are still showing up on `/review` pages. They do not have "Improve" buttons, but they can still be approved or rejected. I'm not sure what causes a post to end up in this limbo state instead of being removed from the queue entirely, which I think is what's supposed to happen.

The suggested edit I noticed this on was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/230952), but it just leads to a "Page Not Found" message now.

Tim Stone provided the following screenshot of another instance [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/922637#922637):

[image: Approve and Reject buttons are present but Improve is not]

Comment: its a caching thing, I am forced to cache stuff quite aggressively there - will see if I can do anything