# When posts leave review queue

Tags: support, review

There are quite a lot info in [FAQ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues)

But I'd like to know exactly how many votes of which type question/answer need to leave queue.

For example(if I understand it correctly) for suggested edit post need one of:

- 3 Approve's
- 3 Reject's
- Improve
- ♦ Approve
- ♦ Reject

Comment: [Been asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-post-removed-from-a-review-queue?rq=1) but didn't get an answer.  This should probably be a dup and we should try to get an answer on that question instead

Comment: @juergend, please make edits more carefully.

Comment: @psubsee2003, didn't noticed that. Voted to close and started bounty instead