# Is it intended that the votes from a previous (invalidated) review combine with the votes from a new review to leave a question closed?

Tags: support, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

**TL;DR**: I completed a [Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80037) review by myself, as a non-mod, and it seems I was able to do so because my "Leave Closed" vote combined with two others from a previous, invalidated review. Is this intended behavior?

Relevant events from the [timeline of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline):

1. [18:33:57](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#history_e89acf3d-2956-4f49-b853-ebb3f9ea9866): Question is closed by five votes (two from a [Close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/80033) review).
2. [18:33:59](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#history_d35aa488-d489-46f9-aed5-763669d79b21): Question is edited and sent for review.
3. [19:47](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#review_80035): The [Reopen votes review (ID# 80035)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80035), with two Leave Closed votes, is invalidated, likely because the question was [deleted two minutes before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#history_4763a2f2-4a27-466b-838a-59abf70ed1cd).
4. [20:30](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#history_2fbff0fa-5bc5-4e1d-843c-317717149581): Question is edited and sent for review.
5. [22:19:47](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#history_485dc6fb-841b-437c-be7d-ebc9f92d1750): Question is "left closed in review" by the previous two reviewers and I.
6. [22:19:48](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/371835/timeline#review_80037): The [Reopen votes review (ID# 80037)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80037), with only my Leave Closed vote, is completed.

Later the question was edited, sent for review again, and reopened. There were also various comments, now deleted, and I edited the question outside the queue for grammar a little before voting to Leave Closed. As far as I know none of those should matter.

The relevant part of the [big honkin' flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5x7.png) from the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) is:

[image: Reopen votes queue flowchart, showing that a significant edit will put a question up for review, 3 or 5 Leave Closed votes will remove it, and 3 Reopen votes will reopen it.]

From [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/) a review task should leave the queue if:

> #### All review queues
>
> - One moderator action - the moderator's review will be the binding, final outcome
> - Post is deleted<sup>[1]</sup>
> - Post is locked (excluding comment-only locks)

> #### Reopen votes
>
> - Three "Leave Closed" reviews
> - Post gets reopened
> - All reopen votes on the question expire
> - The question was added to the queue through an edit after being closed, and the user who edited the question later flags it as spam or rude/abusive, and there are no active reopen votes from others cast more than 15 minutes ago.

The first Reopen votes review works fine by these criteria, as it was properly invalidated once the post was deleted. However, the second review fulfilled none of the criteria, **unless for *'Three "Leave Closed" reviews'* we count the two previous reviews**. From the "left closed in review" event it seems this is the case. However that review had a different initiating edit and a different ID#.

Is this behavior intended/expected?

Comment: I can confirm that before the new review notice system and post history events were rolled out, these review counts used to not be combined.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's likely reopen votes were cast outside the queue and that's why they don't show in the review history events.

Comment: @bad_coder well, there were reopen votes cast outside the queue later - but the question was not reopened until some time *after* the second Reopen Votes review was completed. Thus my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just deployed a fix for this. We did in fact unintentionally combine invalidated leave close votes with new ones. The fix is in place so this issue should be resolved. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you have any data on how many posts this affected?

Comment: @bobble Sorry for the late reply! I don't have information on that. But it looks like an edge case so I expect the number to be small.

Comment: @ShiyaoLi it might be that we can figure that out via StackExchange Data Explorer but I can't find a decent query to start off from