# How many reviewers can perform an action on a review task?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I am trying to learn how [review tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) are implemented, but not finding enough details. Basically my question boils down to what actions can a user perform, how many users can perform an action on the same review task, what actions can they all perform (are they all the same actions, or different?), and what action is the final "nail in the coffin" that removes the item from the review task queue?

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history

I see:

- Recommend Deletion
- Looks Ok
- Delete
- others maybe?

First, who can perform each action. Second, looks like [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32188443) was "responded to" by 4 people.

[image]

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32187844) has both "Recommend Delete" (3 times) and "Delete" (1 time), all different users, who can perform what, what makes the "final verdict"? When is action actually taken on the post to perform the delete, or in the case of "Looks ok" or "Edit", what happens when you perform those actions, does it require a few "Looks ok" to be considered "good"? Or after the first "Looks ok" is it made okay again? That sort of stuff.

Basically I am wondering who can perform what action on the review tasks, and when the review task is "completed" (after n number of actions of some sort). Couldn't find any information on the web about it.

Comment: Who can perform what action is perfectly described in the FAQ you linked yourself.

Comment: From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581): "Six 'Recommend Deletion' or 'Delete' reviews for answers (four on Stack Overflow) [will complete the review]. Note that three 'Delete' reviews (by trusted users) will already delete the post regardless of review queue logic, and therefore complete the review task."

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the links weird I didn't find them after 30 minutes of digging.