# Why were the First Answers and Low Quality Posts reviews for this answer invalidated for no apparent reason?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

What happened to the reviews for [this (now) deleted answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/53831/37236)? Why were they both invalidated without any visible trace? I looked at [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288/323179) and I know that:

- The First Answers task was created because it's a brand new, 1 rep user. I don't think there's any way for the post to leave the queue without a trace like it did.
- The Low Quality Posts task was probably created automatically, since the answer was just a single, short sentence. It could have been removed from the queue by a moderator acting on the flag, but I can't see that happening except by mistake.
- Nobody reviewed either task. It just says *invalidated* on both.
- The deletion of the answer (done with a single mod vote) had nothing to do with this. I saw that the timeline looked exactly the same hours before it was deleted.
- Interestingly, the score was cached at -4, but the real score was +0/-6. I don't know what could have caused this either but I don't think it's related to the tasks being invalidated. (It's probably not cached anymore.)

Timeline:

| When | What |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22 07:31:38Z | post deleted |
| 2022-09-22 00:40:30Z | review Low quality posts |
| 2022-09-22 01:19:45Z | invalidated (Low quality posts) |
| 2022-09-22 00:22:29Z | review First answers |
| 2022-09-22 00:46:20Z | invalidated (First posts) |

([Image of timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ScZq.png))

Is this a bug or is our FAQ incomplete?

Comment: Interesting. Does this on Anime & Manga Meta seem to be a related case—? [Why was this review item in the 'First answers' queue invalidated?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4477)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I think the LQP review there was invalidated by the approved suggested edit. The other difference is that there was a Late Answers review. However, it's possible that the First Answers review was invalidated in the same way as it was here.

Comment: Right, I had the similarity with the First Answers review in mind. (I should have specified since the post was in three review queues, sorry.)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful or not - but as a mod on Arqade, I once cleared (declined) an auto-flag from the Community User for a low quality post on a post that was also a first answer and the timeline for the post is like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U34kO.png

Comment: @TimothyG. Your screenshot makes it clear that dismissing the flag invalidated the LQP review (since the timestamps are close together). It's possible that's what happened the the LQP review here too. However, it doesn't explain what happened to the First answers review, which was invalidated hours beforehand.

Comment: The decreasingly negative negative score removed the post from the queues.

Answer (score 1):

A [staff answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395615/377214) posted yesterday makes it clear why the *First answers* review task was invalidated: essentially, it was due to the fact that the post entered the *Low quality posts* queue.

Basically, back when the review queues were revamped in 2021, there was a change made to eligibility for the *First answers* and *First questions* review queues. Previously, the quality check would run first, and posts would be brought to the then *First posts* queue only if they passed, and instead to *Low quality posts* if they failed (or to *Triage* or *Low quality answers* on sites with this queue layout). However, after the change, posts would be brought to *First questions* or *First answers* immediately, and if they were then later found to fail the quality check (or were brought to a low-quality post queue by user flags), the review there would be invalidated. This was to ensure that all posts were able to be reviewed immediately, rather than there being a wait while the quality check ran.

Neither I nor anyone else updated the FAQ until yesterday because there was no public announcement of this change until then.

<s>As to why the *Low quality posts* task was invalidated, based on the comments, the answer received a suggested edit. Per the FAQ, if a post is edited and the new revision passes the system's quality check, the review task is invalidated. That's probably what happened here, but I can't be sure as I can't see the history.</s> (Scratch that. I misunderstood the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382255/why-were-the-first-answers-and-low-quality-posts-reviews-for-this-answer-invalid/395638?noredirect=1#comment1275082_382255) as referring to this answer but it was in fact referring to a different answer.)

Comment: Wow, it really is fortuitous that someone asked nearly this same question and got a staff answer! Anyway, the LQP review was invalidated in the same second that OP accepted the answer ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gUJf.png)), despite it being unaccepted within the same second (misclick?). Apparently showing the accept vote in the timeline is new, because the old screenshot didn't have it. (There was no suggested edit, which would show up in both screenshots.)

Comment: @Laurel That's likely a coincidence, as far as I can tell. According to the staff answer, the fact that it entered LQP made it ineligible for FA. Also, thanks for pointing out the error in my final paragraph - I've struck it out.

Comment: Why would it be a coincidence when the accept happened in the exact same millisecond that the LQP review was invalidated? (Not FA.) We don't have any other explanation for why the LQP review was invalidated.