# Should I be asked to review edits on deleted posts?

Tags: bug, review, edits, deleted-questions

I just got asked to review an edit on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459678/tweet-an-image-using-twitter-package-in-r

after it had been deleted. At least, I'm pretty sure I was shown it after the deletion.

Is this intentional, or a bug?

If it's not a bug - shouldn't the reviewer be told the post is deleted?

(Perhaps I should mention the edit was the addition of a tag, not some grand rewrite.)

Comment: [Suggested Edit Reviews on Deleted Questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313438)

Comment: This is an extremely old bug, reported back in 2012 and never fixed since: [Suggested edits to deleted posts remaining in /review with Approve/Reject buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127612/suggested-edits-to-deleted-posts-remaining-in-review-with-approve-reject-button)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: What about the second part of my question?

Comment: It's a bug, as according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-marked-completed) review tasks should be invalidated once a post is deleted. The fact that they're not is a bug. Also, since it's a bug, the second part (beginning with "if it's not a bug") isn't relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a review task marked "completed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-marked-completed) - At that *dupe* it says: `Note that three "Delete" reviews ... regardless of review queue logic, and therefore remove the post from the queue (see "All Review Tasks" above)`, only applies to VLQ; but this bug ought to be fixed in that manner ***or*** that FAQ ought to mention that the review of edits on deleted posts is by design (because *someone* can see them) and it's correct on Meta to mark a dupe where the answer ought to go.

Comment: @Rob This question is about the *Suggested Edits* queue. The paragraph you're citing is about the Low Quality Posts queue. While there is some other content that could make your target a valid dupe (specifically, the footnote that says "with the exception of the Suggested Edits queue), this question is *reporting* the bug cited there, while that footnote simply says that it exists. In this case, the bug is already reported, so this can be closed as a dupe of those, but your target is not a valid target for this question.