# Reject or approve suggested edits on deleted post?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

During reviewing suggested edits an edit on deleted post appeared. The post was removed by the post owner. As I am kind of new to reviewing the suggested edits I firstly thought it is an audit and rejected the edit assuming that this is the correct action.

After further looking here and there (e.g. [What happens to a pending suggested edit when a post is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337667/894863)) I found out that deleting a post will remove it from all queues except the suggested edit. It has to be either rejected or approved as regular edit to get out of the queue. I was however not able to find if there is any consensus on how to treat such posts.

There is possibility that if the post is deleted by its owner they might want to edit it eventually themself. Approving such edit might be then harmful. But on the other hand the edit might show them what can be done better in the post.

So is there any consensus or is it up to me what I do?

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344355/282094  and original question (by staff): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123660/282094 --- I would review it correctly.

Comment: That does not answer what I ask, I have seen those posts of course. Also those posts have no real answers.

Comment: How is approving the edit - assuming it's a good edit -  harmful? The post isn't even visible on the site.

Comment: Assuming that OP might removed the post to edit it themself (this sometimes happen), istead of community edit, edit from community is visible to OP.

Comment: Deleting a post has nothing to do with that - the OP may also be working on an edit while the post is live on the site. We just can't take that into consideration. If the OP dislikes the edit, they can reject it themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reject or approve the edit as you would were the post not deleted. If it's a good edit, then accept it - it's possible that the edit moves content from the comments into the question, where it belongs or that it adds detail to a post that was missing, causing it to be deleted. If the poster deleted it themselves, they may find that the edit changes their mind about deleting and they wish to undelete.

As far as I can think, assuming the edit itself is a good one and improves the post, there are no negative impacts of approving such an edit. I can only think of a point of confusion for some - if it's an answer, it will cause the question to be bumped to the top, should the edit be enacted, and those without the ability to see deleted posts may be confused about why the question was bumped - but this is a relatively minor concern.

Our [reviewing FAQ on handling suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) outlines why you would approve or reject a suggested edit and, you may notice, that it makes no mention of deleted posts - because it just isn't a consideration treat them the same.

Comment: Now it is clear to me what should be done and hopefully for others who will ever be curious. The confusion came actually from that there is no such mention in FAQ, maybe it would be helpful to note it.

Comment: From the FAQ: *"Approve if the edit improves the post and ***doesn’t need any additional edits.*** *"* - this almost never applies, and Improve isn't available on deleted posts (at least not for <10k, dunno about after that). That kinda pushes towards reject IMO, and indeed my general work flow is that if a question is closed or deleted, don't approve unless the edit is enough to put it into an openable/undeletable state

Comment: I disagree, @Nick. Heartily. If the edit makes major improvements and misses a few spelling errors, I'm not going to reject it for that. The guide already discourages approving edits that miss most of the errors in the post, which I agree with but an imperfect but otherwise good edit suggestion should be approved.

Comment: @Catija Sure, but an edit which just inlines images, or one which just formats code slightly without looking at any of the textual  question body, or one which only neatens the title. None of them IMO would be worth approving, even if they "improve the post"

Comment: @Nick The first sentence - "if it's a good edit" what you're describing are not good edits.

Comment: Well arguably the FAQ says they _are_ approve worthy edits, for adding information and improving formating respectively, they are _explicitly_ listed as approval reasons. And there is no concrete definition of what constitutes a good edit.

Comment: Since we're working on review queues, I can talk to the PubPlat team about making "improve" an option for all users on deleted posts, @Nick - that might help somewhat. But I think reviewing suggested edits is (and will likely always be) somewhat subjective. We each have our own finely-tuned ideas about when to accept, improve,  or reject and the system is complex enough that none are completely wrong. But when it comes to incomplete edits on deleted posts, some of the concerns with closed posts don't exist, such as popping them into review.

Comment: *"some of the concerns with closed posts don't exist, such as popping them into review."* that is a very fair argument :p

Comment: I tend to lean more on the improve side than the reject side unless there's blatant issues that weren't addressed, such as that example from a while back where someone was making bulk edits to a specific word in a title and ignoring even cases of the same word in the post body, let alone other issues.

Comment: So, it is only when a *moderator* deletes a post that all pending suggested edits are deleted?